# Docker container name vs container id

Tags: docker

I understand that docker has a container name and a container id. As far as I have noticed we can use container name in all places where container id is used. Both are unique for a container if I am not mistaken. Then why does docker maintain two different fields to identify a container? Wouldn't a container name suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The container id is supposed to be unique for the lifetime of your system, while you may over time have many containers with the same name.

Consider:

1. You start a container named `webserver`.
2. You destroy the `webserver` container.
3. You create a new `webserver` container (maybe you were upgrading the software, or built a new image from a different base, or maybe you were just tearing down and re-creating a docker-compose app, etc)

Now there have been two containers named `webserver` on your system at different times. Were they actually the same container? No, of course not. So we see that the name is not unique.

The container id, on the other hand, was different in both cases. This means if we are looking at system logs or audit data, we can differentiate the activity of those two different containers, despite the fact that they shared the same name.